# custom message in validate jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate plugin (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

the default message to warn user to complete required field is "This field is required."
but i want to change it.

how can i change it? I don't want to define a message for each field,I want a new message for all fields.

I use this code,but message doesn't change:

```
$("#RegisterForm").validate({
          messages: {
               required: "This field is ."
          }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found these codes and it did what I want:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, 
     { required: "My message" });
```

Answer (score 2):

After you run your validate method. Do this `$.validator.messages['required'] = 'my message';` Or

alternatively you can pass this as an option in your validate method

```
.validate({
   //options
   messages: {
     required: "my message"
   }
});
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work.but i found these codes and it did what i want: jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
       required: "My message" });